# iPhone 5s starting up takes a lot of time

Tags: battery, iphone, startup

I have an iPhone 5s and when the battery goes dead it takes a long time for it to become useful again after I plug it in. I timed this today and it took 15 minutes to become useful again. All my other phones (Android-based) never had this problem.

My question now is, can I somehow shorten this time for it to start up?

Note: The iPhone is the property of my company, so jailbreaking it is not an option.

Comment: The issue is not it starting up - that process normally takes 10-30 seconds. The issue is that you have completely drained the battery, and in order for it to not shut off again as soon as it comes back on, it needs to build up a battery reserve.

Comment: @tubedogg Yeah but the whole idea is ridiculous. I am responsible enough to keep it connected to power while using it at low battery percentages. Also when fully charged, I can then drain it to 1 % before it shuts down. Why can I thus not start it up when I have 1 %. There must be some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't short the time to use the device. It's normal you can't use your iPhone for at least 5 to 10 minutes untill it's 5%. It will auto startup the system and you can start using it again.